# No such module 'FlutterPluginRegistrant'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, cross-platform

While integrating flutter module in ios native code. I am facing this issue.

```
No such module 'FlutterPluginRegistrant'
```

Pod is already installed but still getting this error. Did anyone able to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

Got it solved by Adding arm64 to the excluded Architecture in project Settings for both pods and app target.

[image]